# Learning Gtkmm, can not display the button anchored in a textview

Tags: gtk, textview, anchor, gtkmm

I am learning gtkmm, and I found an textview example in the gnome.org:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.22/sec-textview-examples.html.en

I change the fill_buffers() code to add button into the textview:

```
void ExampleWindow::fill_buffers()
{
    m_refTextBuffer1 = Gtk::TextBuffer::create();
    m_refTextBuffer1->set_text("This is the text from TextBuffer #1.");

    //learn
    Gtk::TextIter iter = m_refTextBuffer1->get_iter_at_offset(5);
    refAnchor = m_refTextBuffer1->create_child_anchor(iter);

    m_Button_Text.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
                &ExampleWindow::on_button_quit) );
    m_TextView.add_child_at_anchor(m_Button_Text, refAnchor);
    //m_Button_Text.show();


    m_refTextBuffer2 = Gtk::TextBuffer::create();
    m_refTextBuffer2->set_text(
            "This is some alternative text, from TextBuffer #2.");

}
```

and the construtor is:

```
ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()
    : m_Button_Quit(Gtk::Stock::QUIT),
    m_Button_Buffer1("Use buffer 1"),
    m_Button_Buffer2("Use buffer 2"),
    m_Button_Text("Text Button")

{
    set_title("Gtk::TextView example");
    set_border_width(5);
    set_default_size(400, 200);

    fill_buffers();

    m_ButtonBox.pack_start(m_Button_Buffer1, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
    m_ButtonBox.pack_start(m_Button_Buffer2, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
    m_ButtonBox.pack_start(m_Button_Quit, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
    m_ButtonBox.set_border_width(5);
    m_ButtonBox.set_spacing(5);
    m_ButtonBox.set_layout(Gtk::BUTTONBOX_END);

    //Connect signals:
    m_Button_Quit.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
                &ExampleWindow::on_button_quit) );
    m_Button_Buffer1.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
                &ExampleWindow::on_button_buffer1) );
    m_Button_Buffer2.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
                &ExampleWindow::on_button_buffer2) );

    //Add the TreeView, inside a ScrolledWindow, with the button underneath:
    m_ScrolledWindow.add(m_TextView);

    //Only show the scrollbars when they are necessary:
    m_ScrolledWindow.set_policy(Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC, Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

    m_VBox.pack_start(m_ScrolledWindow);

    //Add buttons:
    m_VBox.pack_start(m_ButtonBox, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

    add(m_VBox);

    on_button_buffer1();

    show_all_children();
}
```

So that i can get a button anchored in a textview.
But the code does not work, the button was just displayed as a shape of a cross inside a rectangle and didn't response when clicking.

I also found these sites:

http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?tut-gtk2-txtw-icw

http://www.matrix44.net/blog/?p=1033

and I compare the code between mine and the above websites. I still can not figure out why my code doesn't work...

Great thanks in advance. I have been bothered by this problem for one day...

++++++++++++++++++++

other code may be useful:

```
void ExampleWindow::on_button_quit()
{
    hide();
}

void ExampleWindow::on_button_buffer1()
{
    m_TextView.set_buffer(m_refTextBuffer1);
}

void ExampleWindow::on_button_buffer2()
{
    m_TextView.set_buffer(m_refTextBuffer2);
}
```

Comment: Do you want a row of buttons below the textview, or a button _in_ the text.  This code does the first, or attempts it. If that's what you are attempting, maybe you can add a picture of the result, it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: I want the second one. I have edited the post and maybe my problem is now clear. Thanks for your comment...

Comment: I don't see where you are associating the text buffer with the textview.  Should be a set_buffer somewhere.  Not sure how you're getting anything though.

Comment: Gtk::TextIter iter = m_refTextBuffer1->get_iter_at_offset(5);//get iterator of the buffer
    refAnchor = m_refTextBuffer1->create_child_anchor(iter);//create anchor associated with the iterator
    m_TextView.add_child_at_anchor(m_Button_Text, refAnchor);//add button at the anchor

Comment: m_TextView.set_buffer(m_refTextBuffer1) is needed, iirc.

Comment: yes, that is done by function "on_button_buffer1()"

Answer (score 0):

The button must be created like this:

```
Gtk::Button* m_pbutton = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Button("Text"));
```

and then you can add it to the anchor:

```
m_TextView.add_child_at_anchor(*m_pbutton, refAnchor);
```

Answered this just in case if anyone else needed help.